# Is pumping lemma not applicable for every 'long enough' string in the language?

Tags: computability, regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I recently learnt that a subset of a regular set may not be regular. This is causing me confusion as I imagined if a set is regular then every string longer than $p$ can be pumped in the language. So does a non-regular subset have strings only length $<p$? But if they have length $<p$, can't they be trivially pumped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a subset of a regular language does not have to be based on the length of the strings. It can be constructed based on other properties of the strings.

I assume that by now you already know that the language $L_1$ containing strings with equal numbers of 1 and 0 is not regular. Notice that this is a subset of the language $L_2$ that contains all binary strings, which is trivially regular. It is the property of having equal 0 and 1 that makes it impossible to have a DFA/NFA that will only accept strings from $L_1$.

So if you treat all of $L_1$ as being binary strings (as elements of $L_2$), then all of them can be pumped with respect to this property. But if you consider them as having equal number of 0 and 1, then that is the time where pumping lemma fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn’t think that the ability to be pumped or not depends on respect to which property of the string are we pumping by